# Wordpress post content doesn't show

Tags: wordpress, post, show

i developing calvincavalier.com. but post content doesn’t show. When main page post lists click,post content doesn’t show. Theme is wagazine-Magazine Premium WordPress Theme. How to solve the problem? Let me know solutions.

Answer (score 2):

First of all need to check, theme have **single.php** or not if have then edit this page or add this function

the_content(); or get_the_content(); within wp loop.

Answer (score 1):

There should be a setting in the customizer panel to display posts by category.